# How does NSScrollView works?

Tags: cocoa, macos

How does `NSScrollView` works in mac applications? I've write the following code but the scrolling is not working.

```
NSDictionary *temp=[[ NSDictionary alloc] init  ];
NSScrollView *scroll = [[NSScrollView alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];     
NSArray *dicArray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:dict,dict1,dict2,dict3,dict4, nil];

for (int i=0; i<[dicArray count]; i++) 
{
    int offset=100;
    int x=10;
    int y=20;
    y=y+(i*offset);
    temp= [dicArray objectAtIndex:i];

    NSRect titleRect=NSMakeRect(x,y,100,30);
    NSRect subtitleRect=NSMakeRect(x, y+20, 400, 20);

    NSTextField *title=[[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:titleRect];

    [[title cell] setStringValue:[temp objectForKey:key]];

   [[title cell] setWraps:NO];
   [[title cell] setScrollable:YES];
   [[title cell] setEditable:NO];
   [[title cell] setFont:[NSFont systemFontOfSize:[NSFont systemFontSizeForControlSize:NSMinusSetExpressionType]]];
   [title setDrawsBackground:NO];
   [title setBordered:NO];

    NSTextField *subtitle=[[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:subtitleRect ];
    [[subtitle cell] setStringValue:[temp objectForKey:subkey]];
    [[subtitle cell] setWraps:NO];
    [[subtitle cell] setScrollable:YES];
    [[subtitle cell] setEditable:NO];
    [[subtitle cell] setFont:[NSFont systemFontOfSize:[NSFont     systemFontSizeForControlSize:NSMiniControlSize]]];
    [subtitle setDrawsBackground:NO];
    [subtitle setBordered:NO];
    [scroll addSubview:title];
    [scroll addSubview:categoryOkButton];
  [scroll addSubview:subtitle];


}
[[self window] setContentView:scroll];
[scroll release];
```

Answer (score 20):

My Cocoa is a bit rusty, but `NSScrollView` works in a different way than `UIScrollView`. You don't just add subviews, that doesn't work with `NSScrollView`.

What you need is a container view into which you add all your subviews. So you create an NSView of the appropriate size and add all your views to that container view. Then you set:

```
[myScrollView setDocumentView:myContainerView];
```

See the [Scroll View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSScrollViewGuide/Articles/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003221) for more details.